# Go back to a specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Here's what I want to do:

[image]

If I use `startActivity` I start a new Activity and I can't use StartActivityForResult from **Main Menu** -> **Total**. I would like to go back on the **Main Menu** activity already present in my stack and remove Activities **A**, **B** ,**C** and **Total**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag in your intent (used to start "Main Menu" from "Total")?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

*If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.*

Comment: How can I pass data to my already opened activity with cleartop | singletop without recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove activities A,B,C, and Total from your stack, just call finish() on these 4 activites.

See also : [Tasks & Back stacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) and [Activity task Design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html)

Comment: what do you mean? How can I call finish from Total for A,B,C?